# Deleting files that start with " or '

Tags: linux, special-characters, escape-characters

Sort of noob Linux user here.

I would like to delete a number of files that are contained in a list. The files may contain spaces in their names. I can create a file that goes something like this:

```
rm -f "01. Song1.mp3"
rm -f "02. Song2.mp3"
```

and so on. I used sed to add the "rm -f" and the " character to the end of each line.

Now when I execute that list, it balks. Nothing is really deleted.

Also, when I list my files using ls, the files with spaces start with a ' and others with a "

I think this is part of the problem.

Comment: Escape special characters with a backslash `\\`. Also there are far better options than including the command into the file, you could loop over it line by line. Another option would be to use wildcards in your shell command.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rm -f "01. Song1.mp3"` then `rm` receives 2 arguments with value `-f` and `01. Song1.mp3` without any quotes. Therefore obviously `rm` can't find the desired file. Quotes are only for the shells for special string treatment. If you want to pass quotes to the command you'll need to escape it properly

```
rm -f '"01. Song1.mp3"'
rm -f '"02. Song2.mp3"'
```

or

```
rm -f "\"01. Song1.mp3\""
rm -f \""02. Song2.mp3\""
```

or better just let the shell expand the real name

```
rm -f *01.*.mp3
rm -f *02.*.mp3
```

You can also just type `rm -f \"` or `rm -f '"` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> so the shell will auto complete the file name with proper escaping. You should avoid typing names literally